# Several Prints into df

Tags: python

Here is a part of the code to calculate R2 from several regression algorithms:

```py
print("Random Forest Performance")
print(metrics.r2_score(y_test, Y_pred_random_forest))
    
print("Bagging_Regressor Performance")
print(metrics.r2_score(y_test, Y_pred_Bagging_Regressor))
    
print("Extra_Trees_Regressor Performance")
print(metrics.r2_score(y_test, Y_pred_Extra_Trees_Regressor))
```

How could be prints better displayed? Is there any way to to bring the results more readable - in a dataframe for example.

Here is the output that I am currently getting:

[image]

Comment: Append all your results to a dictionary or a list.

Once done, create a DataFrame regrouping them with the right names for columns to understand which is which.

Answer (score 1):

Arrange the titles and the predictions into lists and the build a dataframe with pandas. Something like this should work:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics

titles = ["Random Forest Performance", "Bagging_Regressor Performance", "Extra_Trees_Regressor Performance"]
y_test = [1,2,4,5,6,7]
# Build an array y_preds = [Y_pred_random_forest, Y_pred_Bagging_Regressor, ... ]
y_preds = [[1,2,3,5,6,8],  # Y_pred_random_forest
           [2,2,4,5,6,7],  # Y_pred_Bagging_Regressor
           [3,1,4,5,7,8]]  # Y_pred_Bagging_Regressor

# build dataframe          
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Algorithms': titles})
df['R2 score'] = list(map(lambda x: metrics.r2_score(y_test, x), y_preds))
df.head(50)
```

Result:

[image]